# c: how to call process callback function from another process

Tags: c, winapi

How can I call a process callback function from another process?

My exe is loaded at 0x400xxx, I'm loading another exe which sets up callbacks but is at 0x400xxx too.

How to call this far magic?

Answer (score 4):

In most operating systems (I think you're talking about Microsoft Windows here?) you can not make function calls between two processes.  Each process has it's own memory space and they are isolated from each other.

You can communicate between two processes using inter-process communication mechanisms such as pipes.  In Windows you can also use synchronization objects such as events or semaphores between processes.  If you elaborate on what you are trying to do I can provide some suggestions.

Comment: Yes thanks Guy, i know all that. But that's why SetThreadContext() and other alike code injection is made for. I need relative visible point how i can do that in ms windows.

Comment: @Sergey: With SetThreadContext you might be able to set the instruction pointer of another thread, however that's not a function call. It's more like a branch. Can you explain what you're trying to do here?

Comment: The debugging functions are explained here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679303%28v=VS.85%29.aspx If you're debugging another process you can pretty much do anything you want.  Perhaps you're looking to create some instructions in memory and then execute them?